# solving H-captcha without a form submit / button?

Tags: python, selenium, 2captcha

I'm using the anti captcha api to solve the h-captcha of a website but I can't give it, to send the result of the captcha solution here I show you my code the website.

```
    def Solved_Hcaptcha(url, api, site_key):
        solver = hCaptchaProxyless()
        solver.set_verbose(1)
        solver.set_key(api)
        solver.set_website_url(url)
        solver.set_website_key(site_key)
        g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
        return g_response
    
    g_response = Solved_Hcaptcha("https://www.xhibition.co/pages/raffle-1?t=1600836042264", api, site_key)
   driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByName("g-recaptcha-response")[0].innerHTML = "{g_response}"')
   driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByName("h-captcha-response")[0].innerHTML = "{g_response}"')
   sleep(1)
   driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#challenge-form").submit()')
```

this is the site where the h-captcha appears
https://www.xhibition.co/pages/raffle-1?t=1600836042264

on other websites if I have solved with the api using form.submit () but this website does not have the form to submit the solution.

[image]

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution?